# Oracle: How do I get the sequence number of the row just inserted?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get the sequence number of the row just inserted?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

insert ... returning.

```
declare
   s2 number;
 begin
   insert into seqtest2(x) values ('aaa') returning seq into s2;
   dbms_output.put_line(s2);
 end;
```

"seq" here refers to the name of the column whose value you want to store into variable s2.

in python:

```
myseq=curs.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
curs.prepare("insert into seqtest2(x) values('bbb') returning seq into :x")
curs.execute(None, x=myseq)
print int(myseq.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** as Mark Harrison pointed out, this assumes that you have control over how the id of your inserted record is created. If you have full control and responsibility for it, this *should* work...

---

Use a stored procedure to perform your insert and return the id.

eg: for a table of names with ids:

```
PROCEDURE insert_name(new_name    IN   names.name%TYPE, 
                      new_name_id OUT  names.id%TYPE)
IS
    new_id names.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT names_sequence.nextVal INTO new_id FROM dual;
    INSERT INTO names(id, name) VALUES(new_id, new_name);
    new_name_id := new_id;
END;
```

Using stored procedures for CRUD operations is a good idea regardless if you're not using an ORM layer, as it makes your code more database-agnostic, helps against injection attacks and so on.

Answer (score 6):

My answer in C#, considering that table "testtable" has an "ID" collumn as PK with an autoinc sequence and field "testname" is a varchar field.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("your connection string here");


        string sql = "INSERT INTO testtable(testname) VALUES('testing2') RETURNING id INTO :LASTID";
        OracleParameter lastId = new OracleParameter(":LASTID", OracleDbType.Int32);

        lastId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(lastId);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Last ID: " + lastId.Value.ToString());
            cn.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey(false);


    }
}
}
```