# get sequence number in cx_oracle python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Im trying to execute a insert statement that has a sequence number column but unable to determine the returning value.

When I execute the below statement without binding seqvalue I get a error. When I initialize the seqvalue to 0 and bind it the output is 0.

code

```
    col2 = 'test'
    qry=insert into table1 (col1,col2) value (seq1.nextval,:col2) returning col1 into :seqvalue

   cur.excute(qry,:col2)
```

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: Like this? [Oracle: How do I get the sequence number of the row just inserted?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/361309/222914)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: How do I get the sequence number of the row just inserted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361304/oracle-how-do-i-get-the-sequence-number-of-the-row-just-inserted)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the bind variable and prepare statements which would use the same oracle method as SEQ.nextval.
Steps :

1. Make a DB connection using cx_Oracle.
2. Obtain a cursor from DB connection.
3. Declare variables : which will be pushed into Oracle insert statement.
   for example below:

var_CHANGES = 'Test Changes'
var_COMMENTS = 'Test'

4. Make a statement with next line characters as show in example below:

```html
statement = "INSERT"                    + "\n" + \
       "INTO   CHANGE_LOG"    + "\n" + \
       "( CHANGE_LOG_ID"      + "\n" + \
       ", CHANGE_TYPE"             + "\n" + \
       ", CHANGE_DATE"            + "\n" + \
       ", COMMENTS )"              + "\n" + \
       "VALUES"                    + "\n" + \
       "( CHANGE_LOG_SEQ.nextval" + "\n" + \
       ", :bCHANGE_TYPE"               + "\n" + \
       ", sysdate"              + "\n" + \
       ", :bCOMMENTS )"
```

then, using regex substitution format the query :

```html
stmt = re.sub('\s+',' ',stmt.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',''))
```

5. execute the query using cursor.execute. as per the above example:

```html
cursor.execute(statement, bCHANGE_TYPE=var_CHANGES     \
                        , bCOMMENTS = var_COMMENTS )
```

6. Execute the commit statement

So, here you can use SQL nextval() and sysdate as in the normal SQL query.
This should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sequence in database:
   Create sequence my_seq minvalue 1 maxvalue 99999999999999 increment by 1 start with 1 nocache noorder nocycle;
2. Create a Oracle function to generate sequence numbers in database:
   Create or replace function gen_seq 
   Return number
   Is
         Seq_value number;
   Begin

   ```
     Select my_seq.nextval into seq_value from dual;
     Return seq_value;
   ```

   End;
3. self.emp_id = cur.callfunc('gen_seq', int)
4. Use self.emp_id as bind variable in order to insert into your database.

Any doubt. Please feel free to ask.